# Raw strings into HttpRequest/HttpResponse using ASP.NET 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

We're manipulating raw requests and responses.  We're looking to read the raw HTTP message from the socket, and convert it to an Microsoft.AspNet.Http.HttpRequest object.  We want the same for responses, that is converting raw text into in a Microsoft.AspNet.Http.HttpResponse object that can be manipulated as needed.

The question:
How can I convert raw strings into HttpRequest/HttpResponse objects, using the new classes in ASP.NET 5?

Edit:
Ok, so the above is, apparently, not clear enough.  Here's a code snippet that gets to the meat of what we're after:

```
static void Main()
{
    string http = @"CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.0" + "\r\n" +
                "Host: www.google.com:443" + "\r\n" +
                "Content-Length: 0" + "\r\n" +
                "Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive" + "\r\n" +
                "Pragma: no-cache" + "\r\n" +
                "\r\n\r\n";
     Microsoft.AspNet.Http.HttpRequest request = ParseHttp(http);
}

static Microsoft.AspNet.Http.HttpRequest ParseHttp(string http)
{
    //Magic goes here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a `new DefaultHttpContext()`. That will get all the collections set up for you. Then you can just set the properties as needed. https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http/DefaultHttpContext.cs#L34

I don't have a simple example for you to actually parse the request, but I can show you one where I did something very similar with HttpRequestMessage & HttpResponseMessage from the client side: https://github.com/Tratcher/HttpClient/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Net.Http.Client/HttpConnection.cs#L29-L41

Comment: This is really close to what we're looking for.  How robust is the private method "CreateResponseMessage"?  

Here's where the nuget package is for this dll in case anyone else is looking: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martinkearn/archive/2015/06/17/using-httpclient-with-asp-net-5-0.aspx

Comment: FYI: the Microsoft.Net.Http.Client package is obsolete since System.Net.Http now works on CoreClr, mac, linux, etc..

Comment: No it's not very robust code. It was the bare minimum prototype to run on CoreClr via Sockets while we were waiting for System.Net.Http. It worked fine for what we needed it for, but it is not a hardened general purpose solution. Side note: HTTP requires "\r\n" line endings, not "\n" as shown in your sample above.

Comment: Does the .net 5 framework have System.Net.Http's current parsing mechanism open source?  I didn't see it here: [link](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpRequestMessage.cs).  Where would we be able to find such code?

Comment: CoreCLR (.Net 5) System.Net.Http does not use managed code to process requests, it calls into WinHttp on windows and libcurl on mac/linux.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Proxy implementation in the aspnet repo on GitHub?

https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy

You might get some ideas from there. I'm guessing you want to do something like this:

https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Proxy/ProxyMiddleware.cs#L70

Comment: Hey, second link is dead :)